# Searching on whole title returns no results

Tags: search

When a client site is searched by the whole title, the search results return zero.
If I search by a few words in the entry title then the entry is returned in the search results.

If i search with the whole title in quotes, I get the entry in the search results.

I am expecting the entry to be returned when searching on whole title.

So is this a bug to file or mismatched expectation?

Search query :
results?q=Help+for+seafarers+when+they+need+it+most

Comment: Can you share the full string you are searching for and is this happening on the front-end or CP or both?

Answer (score 1):

I don’t think it’s a bug, that’s what the docs describe, although I would tend to make the same assumption that you’ve made about how it *should* work.

Either way you can search for a contains, or an exact match at the same time:

```
.search(search_query "OR \"" ~ search_query ~ "\"")
```